# $scope.$watch is not triggering when checkbox value changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can I express my problem I'm not sure but 
**$scope.$watch is not triggering when checkbox value changes**
in my project.

I've just created the below code snippet in order to show my problem to you but, unfortunately, it is working properly!!

The same approach exists in my project (of course, variable names and function names are different) but it isn't working!!

Do you have any idea about why my code can prevent to work of `$scope.$watch` in my project? I have tried many things but it is still not working!!

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="count==100" ng-true-value="100"
       ng-false-value="99999" ng-model="count">  {{caption}} 
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count = 100;
        $scope.$watch("count", function(a,b) {
            if ($scope.count==100){
                 $scope.caption = ' Showing first 100 records';
             } else {
                 $scope.caption = ' Showing all records';
             }        
          });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works. The $scope.$watch is being triggered each time when you change the checkbox.

Comment: @AKA yes I'm telling this. It is now working but the same code doesn't work in my project

Comment: In your real code, your checkbox is probably inside an ng-if or an ng-repeat, or some other directive that defines its own scope. So the count in the model is not in the controller scope, but in a different, child scope. Always have a dot in your ng-model ex: ng-model="someObject.count"), always initialize the model in the controller (ex: $scope.someObject = {}).

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Have you included your controller code or file link to this controller in your HTML file?

Comment: @JBNizet no there is no any directive but I'm going to try the dot notation now.

Comment: @AKA there is no any error in console. I have included the controller. Except for that part, angular is working properly.

Comment: can you create a plunkr @Grcn

Comment: @JBNizet OMG!! it has worked!! after the dot notation, it has worked properly. You have saved my life :) Can you please explain what is the difference between xxx.count and count?? (by the way, my real variable name was not "count"  it cannot be a "Reserved Word")

Comment: Some directives, like ngt-if or ng-repeat, create their own child scope, which inherits from the current, controller scope. So, if you have ng-model="foo" inside such a directive, angular will bind the value to the child scope (`childScope.foo = enteredValue` instead of `controllScope.foo = enteredValue`). If you initialize the model in the scope and use `ng-model="model.foo"`, then angular will do `childScope.model.foo = enteredValue`, and that will work fine because childScope.model is resolved, through inheritance, to the same object as controllerScope.model.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `ng-checked` clearly states that `ng-checked` should not be used together with `ng-model`.

From the Docs:

> ## ngChecked
>
> Sets the `checked` attribute on the element, if the expression inside `ngChecked` is truthy.
>
> **Note** that this directive should not be used together with [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), as this can lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> [— AngularJS `ng-checked` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)